# Efficient way to start multiple shell scripts from single shell script

Tags: shell-script

This is what my code looks like

`master_script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod +x *
declare -A test=(
    ["echo1"]="sh `pwd`/echo1.sh"
    ["echo2"]="sh `pwd`/echo2.sh"
    ["echo3"]="sh `pwd`/echo3.sh")

log="$base_path"
for var in ${!test[@]}
do
    `${test[$var]} >> $var.log`
    echo "$var Started! :-)"
done
```

`echoX.sh` scripts looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;do
    echo "This is from Test1"
    #some Code
    echo "Eching the Output"
    #some other code!
    sleep 60
done
```

The idea is ok, but as you know, the control is waiting at `${test[$var]} >> $var.log`. Each `echoX.sh` is `while` loop, So the control is waiting to complete!. I want to start ALL scripts

How can I resolve this issue?. NOTE: There are future planings implement features like, staring single script like

`./master_script.sh start echo1`, --> Will start only echo1

`./master_script.sh stop echo1` ---> Will stop only echo1

`./master_script.sh start all`--> will starts all scripts

So, thats why I followed above procedure.

**There are some other thoughts like.(*Which don't want to do!*)**

`echox.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is from Test1"
#some Code
echo "Eching the Output"
#some other code!
```

`nohup_echoX.sh`

```
#!bin/bash
while true;do
  ./echoX.sh >> test.log 2>&1 &
done
```

Then in the `mater_script.sh`, ill add the `./nohup_echoX.sh` in `for` loop.

So, is there any way to implement this. And more thing, I saw(`ps aux | grep <NAME>`), there are multiple instances of same process are running. So, how can I control this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
`${test[$var]} >> $var.log`
```

to

```
"${test[$var]}" >> "$var.log" &
```

Answer (score 4):

[Gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) will nicely allow you to run multiple processes from shell script in parallel, waiting for their completion.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) which is really cool. easy start, easy config, easy manage!. Check out this [Blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps) to know how to use and config :-)